# Skype plugin in C#

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, authorization, skype

I write system, that collects informations about local system. It's a system like admin-client. Client collects and sends log to admin. There's of course possibility to get this log by admin over LAN, but I'd like to add option send log over Internet.

I thought about skype. Client must have logged skype and when admin (of course there must be appropriate authorization, but it's separate topic) send request by skype - client must e.g. connect to SQL database or simple file with collected log and send it over skype.

How can I do this?
Is this the best way? Plugin in skype? What lib may I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an either/or situation.

- If you want an administrator who is already using Skype to be able to send this information over the internet, then a plugin which exposes that functionality in Skype is the way to go.
- If you want the administrator to be able to send the information over Skype's network, but not necessarily have to have the application running (perhaps this will be done through the application that gathers data), then using the API to control Skype externally is better.

You can find the documentation for Skype here:

http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Skype has a COM API called [Skype4COM](http://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com) which you could use through [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in order to access Skype.

It should be noted that [SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit) is now available for use in both [embedded](http://developer.skype.com/account/subscriptions/join?program=31) and [desktop](http://developer.skype.com/account/subscriptions/join?program=11) programs.  There's a small one-time registration fee (currently $5 USD) for each program, but it will allow you to access Skype without actually using any UI functionality (it's completely up to you to provide the interface).

Answer (score 1):

Until [SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit) is released, you're limited to the [Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories). However according to the [docs](http://developer.skype.com/resources/public_api_ref.zip) this API only allows to specify the recipient and open the file dialog, initiating a file transfer automatically seems to be impossible (see "OPEN FILETRANSFER" in the docs).

I suggest you use an open protocol like HTTP or FTP instead.